# PHP-PDO: Is PDO safe only for Inputing to the Database not Outputting from DB?

Tags: php, database, browser, pdo

Using `PDO` you'd moslty come across lines like:

```
$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");

$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");

$dbh->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET col1= ?");
```

These are famous to being great for *Storing* data in the `Db`, *Getting* Data from the DB, and *Updating* data in the Db.

When learning `PDO`, it's strongly emphasized to NOT **bother** `Sanitizing` your `data`, `PDO` will do the **Sanitization**.... You can ***TRUST*** it 100%....

Now, when it comes to the safety of output `DATA` from a query such as:

`"SELECT * FROM table_name",`

A malicious code like: `OR 1=1` will NOT affect the `Database`... However, now that `PDO` only took care of the `DATA` when being stored in the `DB` for `DB` Protection, on **output**, if a `column` contains *malicious* code like `"<script>alert("Hacked")</script>"`, this seems to `alert` **"Hacked"** in the user's browser.

What precautions is there for this?

Do we have to `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` the `data` *manually* or **what is the best way to secure both the Storing and retrieving and displaying of `DATA`?**

Comment: Thx... then what is the Best way you know of to ***take care about that in your application (or another layer which takes output responsibility)*** ? ...interesting, am sure many do not realize this... plz your suggestion is highly valued

Comment: I need to "Mark" something as an answer... "Answer" instead of commenting?.... I think your point is Solid and Vital. I'd highly appreciate if you'd have little code as part of your answer. thx for these Educational Comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Data storage*

Database has no idea what data is stored in it. If it's correct (i.e. all quotes or whatever are escaped properly) - then data is correct and will be stored correctly. But for what purposes - html/javascript/executable code/script code/or/whatever - DB has no idea, so you'll need to take care about that in your application (or another layer which takes output responsibility).

*PDO*

And so does PDO - it's intention is not in data logic at all. It's just driver, and, thus, it may provide only proper data escaping in terms of storing in database. That's why all specific things can not be caught there (and they shouldn't)

*"Best way"*

There's no "best way". Different data needs different ways to maintain safe output. For html, it's `htmlspecialchars()`/`htmlentities()` - but for other data types it will be other things. And you should know exactly what are you doing (i.e. what are you outputting). Main idea would be - store your data as it is - in database and provide safe output when it's needed (i.e. when output will be done). I.e. split database, data logic and output and provide correct functioning for each of that part.

Comment: I mostly re-read the line: **it may provide only proper data escaping in terms of database *storage.***

Comment: I think a better term than database storage would be database storage/manipulation.